# Detect Special Characters in user input

Tags: javascript, user-input, special-characters

Trying to detect if user input is a special character, Have Tried a couple different things but cant get the code to run correctly keeps outputting user character is a capital letter.

```
let user_character = prompt("Enter either a Capital Letter, Lowercase Letter, or a Number.");   

//Checks if the input character is an integer.
if(Number.isInteger(user_character)){
    console.log(`You input: ${user_character} \nThat is a number.`);                         
}

//Checks if the input character is a capital letter.
else if(user_character === user_character.toUpperCase()){
    console.log(`You input: ${user_character} \nThat is an upper case letter.`);                
}

//Checks to see if the input character is a lower case letter.
else if(user_character === user_character.toLowerCase()){
    console.log(`You input: ${user_character} \nThat is a lower case letter`);                
}

//Checks to see if the input is a special Character
else if(user_character ===){
    console.log("You input: " + user_character + ", That is a special character");
}

else{
    console.log("Unfortunately: " + user_character + ", Does not match the requested input.");       
}
```

Comment: Careful!  `'?' == '?'.toUpperCase()` is `true`, but `?` is not strictly a "capital letter".  What that actually tests for is that it **does not contain a lowercase letter**.  There's a logical difference between "contains an uppercase letter" and "does not contain a lowercase letter"

Answer (score 1):

For to check for special character, one solution is adding them in a variable

```
var specialCharacters= /[ `!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?~]/;
```

And then you can check by using the RegExp test() e.g.

```
var specialCharacters= /[ `!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?~]/;

// if is not any special character
if(!specialCharacters.test(user_character)){
       //do something
}
```

You can check more info for the RegExp test() here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp

Answer (score 0):

Since most characters you might consider "special" don't have uppercase variants, your test to see if the character is uppercase will always succeed.

```js
const specialCharacter = "$";
console.log(specialCharacter === specialCharacter.toUpperCase());
```

You need to first decide which characters you consider to be "special" (or which ones are not and do a negative test) and then write the test for that **before** your test for being uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regular Expressions.

```js
//Checks to see if the input is a special Character
let pattern = /A-Za-z0-9/;
else if (!pattern.test(user_character)){
    console.log("You input: " + user_character + ", That is a special character");
}
```

This should work.